# The inequality while proving the convergence of $\sum a_n^2$

Tags: calculus

I was solving this problem:

**Prove this**: When $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ absolutely converges, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2$ converges.

So I came up with these two possible solutions:

**sol 1**. $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0\Rightarrow \;\mathrm{for} \; n\geq N, \; \left|a_n-0\right|<\epsilon=1$

$\displaystyle \qquad\therefore \sum_{n\geq N}^{\infty}a_n^2\leq\sum_{n\geq N}^{\infty}|a_n|<\infty$

**sol 2**. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|\cdot|a_n|=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|\right)^2<\infty$

I think that **sol 1** has no problem with itself, but I found people saying that there is an inequality in **sol 2**, somewhat like: $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2\leq\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|\right)^2$$
Why should there be an inequality? I thought that for all $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$, only equality works.

Comment: Why would you expect equality at all? It won't be an equality for finite sums either. E.g., $a^2+b^2\le (a+b)^2$ if $a,b\ge 0$ because the right side has a term $2ab$ that is not on the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n| \cdot |a_n|=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| \right)^2$$

Sums do not work like this; the sum of products is not the product of sums. As a counterexample, suppose $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

but the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Even if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges -- such as if $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ -- there is no equality because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2=\frac{\pi^4}{90} \approx 1.08$ but $\left( \frac{\pi^2}{6} \right)^2 \approx 2.70$.

Comment: Oh, I was misunderstanding. Thanks!